# How to restrict Profile Edit/Create Visibility?

Tags: drupal, profile

I have Profile which I need to provide access to only user who are Active Members, So I have restricted Listings to Active Members only but when I go to the

> civicrm/profile/edit?gid=20&reset=1
>
> civicrm/profile/create?gid=20&reset=1
>   It still displays the profile page.
>   How can I make sure edit and create profile is displayed only if its an active member ?

When I login with a member who is not a member and access the url of create/edit profile, it provides me the option to create or edit, how can I prevent that using civicrm settings ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will need to update the CMS permission to remove view/edit data using profile. Configure ACL from CiviCRM UI to restrict group of contacts to update their contact using profile.

Note: I guess changing the permission will result in profile not available for any user if they dont have access to. If you want to restrict specfic profile and enable all others them i think you can use [profile hooks](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/list/#profile-hooks) to return access denied.

Comment: thanks, I will work on returning access denied drupal way using Profile Hook https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildProfile/  and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_access_denied/7.x is there any way we can do that in CiviCRM?